# Tab switching for google chrome via mouse wheel for latest versions of chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, mouse

There have been a lot of updates since the last answered question on this topic, including removal of the chrome toolbox from the extension site.

While I have been able to, for some time, continue to have my tabs scroll by manually porting chrome toolbox and enabling it.  However, recently this method has stopped working.

I would rather not have to bind the ctrl+tab and ctrl+shift+tab to my mouse up/down as it would not allow me to scroll when over the page itself.  I know one of the reasons that this was removed was that it interferes with youtube playback somehow, but I rarely use youtube and this functionality is more important to me.

Is there any current and reputable extensions that will provide this functionality?  Is there a way to enable and/or modify the browser myself in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a Chrome extension doing this, but [this post](https://plus.google.com/115670442023408995787/posts/WYPqqk2j9UB) provides a little Windows program that brings back this functionality.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser! Can you summarize what that program does exactly? Maybe how you came about it? Just a link makes people think spam, so context would be helpful